# RVM won't install and causes errors

Tags: rvm

I am trying to install  RVM on Mac OSX 10.5. When I do I get the following errors.

```
mitch:~ mitch$ bash < <( curl http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/releases/rvm-install-head )
      % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                     Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
    100   185  100   185    0     0    347      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
    bash: line 1: html: No such file or directory
    bash: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
    'ash: line 2: `<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
```

I also tried to install using this:

```
bash < <(curl -s https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/install/rvm)
```

Which does not produce any errors but also does not install or download anything.

Any ideas on how I can get RVM to install?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this, works for me

```
bash < <( curl https://rvm.io/releases/rvm-install-head )
```

or use `-L` option to tell `curl` to follow `301` redirection

```
bash < <( curl -L http://rvm.io/releases/rvm-install-head )
```

Comment: Thanks Zifei I used the second line but also had to use the -k option to get around the security certificate error. The complete line I used is: bash < <( curl -k -L http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/releases/rvm-install-head )

Answer (score 1):

I used this command for RVM installation and it works fine.....

```
bash -s stable < <(curl -s https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do `ls ~/.rvm` and see if the directory has been created. If it has, delete it using `rm -rf ~/.rvm`. That will clean out any partially installed RVMs.

Then do `bash < <(curl -s https://rvm.io/install/rvm)`. If should be successful, and will present an introduction screen if it was.

Follow the directions in the intro text, and append RVM's initialization command to the end of your `~/.bashrc` file. Be sure to read the directions about its placement.

Type `rvm notes` and read what it says for MacOS prerequisites. You'll need the latest XCode from Apple, which is free, but it's a big download.

At that point you should be able to use RVM to install some Rubies into its sandbox.

Comment: I checked for the .rvm directory and none were created. Then I typed bash < <(curl -s https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/install/rvm) as instructed and nothing happens.  Nothing gets downloaded and no welcome screen appears. I only get a new command line: mitch:~ mitch$ . This is driving me nuts.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have the same problem I had, and it was actually to do with curl.

You need to enable ssl support in curl, I found the solution with mac ports, in this post

http://naleid.com/blog/2009/03/16/enabling-https-support-in-curl-installed-through-macports-on-osx/

```
sudo port -f upgrade curl +ssl
```

Note the +ssl option which adds this support.